# Qt: Connecting signals and slots

Tags: c++, qt, signals, slot

I have a `MainWindow` that contains a custom widget with a `QTextEdit` in it.
I would like to create a signal/slot between the `MainWindow` and the `QTextEdit`.

In `MainWindow` I have:

```
QObject::connect(ui->Header,
        SIGNAL(ui->Header->getTextWidget()->textChanged()),
        this, // this : MainWindow
        SLOT(headerUpdated())); // Function of MainWindow
```

But this does not work. Is it even possible to create such signal/slot combination?

Comment: This is possible. Please read [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) on signals and slots or one of the other hundred questions here about it.

Comment: The first argument to `connect` should be the object which emits the signal, this is going to be whatever `getTextWidget` contains, not `Header`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

why bother - let Qt do all the magic :) Just name your slot (in the mainWindow) like that:

```
void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);
```

And you're done. More info here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName
important: "object name" part means name of the object - not variable name. If you design your window in QtDesigner it should be set (in ui.setupUi method). if not - set it manually (by calling [setObjectName](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#objectName-prop)

Just watch out for number of arguments in your slot. Here's what I do: I simply copy the signal prototype (from from header or the doc - eg: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged - watch out again for the weird whitespace between "::" and method name [some kind of an unbreakable-zerowidth-space] - only present when copying from v5.x doc), and prepend it with `on_objectName_`. That guarantees, that your slot will be ok to connect it to the signal

Comment: I didn't know there was another way. Thanks!