# connect expected token ';' got ')'

Tags: c++, qt

I try to connect a signal to my own slot but when I do that my code gets red underlined and with the text

> connect expected token ';' got ')'

It goes away if I put a ; in middle of the code but as expected I then gets a compiler error.

Code with underlined red:

```
connect(name,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(content->sections->fields[count].onActionFieldName(QString)));
```

No underline but compiler error:

```
connect(name,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(content->sections->fields[count].onActionFieldName(QString);));
```

My best guess is that it's something else that causes that error than that part of the code and found out that the compiler doesn't like that I have a ';' after my function declaration. And it also complains on that it returns void.

```
#include <QString>

class Field
{
public:
    QString label;
    QString content;
    Field();
    virtual ~Field();
    void virtual Save();

public slots:
    void onActionFieldName(QString name); //16: error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
};
```

Comment: `content->sections->fields[count].onActionFieldName(QString))` is an attempt to call a function, passing it a type for the parameter. That is an error. The name of the function is  `Field::onActionFieldName`, if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 4):

To be able to take advantage of signals and slots, your class must inherit from QObject and define a macro "QObject".

```
class Field : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QString label;
    QString content;
    Field();
    virtual ~Field();
    void virtual Save();

public slots:
    void onActionFieldName(QString name); //16: error: C2238: unexpected token(s) preceding ';'
};
```

Your connect function call is wrong as well, please check following guide how it should be properly called:

[Qt Documentation: Signals & Slots](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html)

Comment: The OP's `connect()` statement is also wrong, you should address that too.

Answer (score 1):

To use signals and slots your class needs to inherit from QObject as pointed out by szulak but also:

```
connect(name,SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)),this,SLOT(content->sections->fields[count].onActionFieldName(QString);));
```

This is wrong, the syntax of `QObject::connect()` is

```
QObject::connect(sender, SIGNAL(signalEmitted()), receiver, SLOT(onSignalEmitted());
```

From the looks of it in your case the receiver should be `&(content->sections->fields[count])` and not `this`

Answer (score 0):

Once you deal with compile errors (as @szulak described) - you don't have to explicitly connect your slot to the signal. You can use auto-connect mechanizm as described here: [Qt: Connecting signals and slots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28190445/qt-connecting-signals-and-slots/28190550#28190550)
So, to react on `textChanged(QString)` signal of some kind of a widget named `name` it would be enough to declare:

```
public slots:
    void on_name_textChanged(QString name)
```

Nevertheless - if you choose to connect manually, your connect statement should look like:

```
connect( name, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), this, SLOT(onActionFieldName(QString)) );
```

see the doc: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#connect