# Qt creator : expected token ';' got ')'

Tags: c++, qt

When I try to connect to QLabel in Qt my code become underlined with red line. Text of the error message is:

```
expected token ';' got ')'
```

I tried fixing that problem with help of [connect expected token ';' got ')'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29194960/connect-expected-token-got), but it didn't help.
mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QObject::connect(ui->desert, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg"))));
    QObject::connect(ui->koala, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Koala.jpeg"))));
    QObject::connect(ui->penguins, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Penguins.jpeg"))));
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

desert, koala and penguins are QRadioButtons, label is a QLabel. I pasted them in project in mainwindow.ui with help of Design Tab. And there is a problem as in beginning of post.
Underlined strings:

```
QObject::connect(ui->desert, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg"))));
QObject::connect(ui->koala, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Koala.jpeg"))));
QObject::connect(ui->penguins, SIGNAL(toggled(true)), ui->label, SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Penguins.jpeg"))));
```

Actually, code compiles, but after toggling QRadioButtons nothing happens, so after that there isn't any changes in label.
String `ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg"))` works.
What should I correct in my code?

Comment: Prefer using the "pointer-to-member" syntax for signal/slot connections, rather than the string based one. Then you won't get funny errors or missing action at runtime, but rather a compile time error you can fix.

Comment: `SLOT(setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg")))` doesn't do what you want at all. `SLOT` is a macro that turns its insides into a string and then looks up a member function by that string, but there is no member function `setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg"))`. Maybe there is a member function `setPixmap(QPixmap)`. You should switch to [the new signal slot syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/New_Signal_Slot_Syntax) that would have given you a compile time error instead of a run time error.

Comment: Also consider using [`QT_FATAL_WARNINGS`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/debug.html#warning-and-debugging-messages) so the program stops when it encounters an error such as this so you have a chance to debug it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`moc` generated method like `qt_static_metacall` after compilation. Your code viewed like for call:

```
if (_c == QMetaObject::InvokeMetaMethod) {
    QLabel *_t = static_cast<QLabel *>(_o);
    Q_UNUSED(_t)
    switch (_id) {
    case 0: _t->setPixmap((*reinterpret_cast< int(*)>(_a[1]))); break;
```

Therefore variables in declaration not worked for callback 'setPixmap' on runtime executed. You need declaration yourself method and call `setPixmap` with necessary arguments. Example:

```
QObject::connect(ui->desert, SIGNAL(toggled(bool)), this, SLOT(mySlot(bool)));

// Something code
void MainWindow::mySlot(bool)
{
    QString value;
    // something for get correct value
    ui->label->setPixmap(value);
}
```

Sorry for my English!

Comment: What? That did not parse as english for me. Could you try to clarify?

Comment: He wanted to say that parameters, which are come from signal must be received by slot with same order. for example:
SIGNAL(mySIGNAL(int, bool)), this, SLOT(mySLOT(int, bool)));
SIGNAL(mySIGNAL(QString, QVector<int>)), this, SLOT(mySLOT(QString, QVector<int>)));

Answer (score 0):

I did it with this code in mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtGui>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_desert_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Desert.jpeg"));
}

void MainWindow::on_koala_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Koala.jpeg"));
}

void MainWindow::on_penguins_toggled(bool checked)
{
    ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap("D:/Qt Projects/DZ3/Penguins.jpeg"));
}
```

Anyway, thanks for all who tried to help me!